# Why Razor HTML Partial View not rendering between 'If' Block?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to render a Razor html Partial view based on a ViewBag condition, but I always get compliation errors.

```
 @{

     if (ViewBag.Auth)
     {
        @Html.RenderPartial("_ShowUserInfo")
     }

 }
```

I also tried...

```
 @if (ViewBag.Auth)
 {
    @Html.RenderPartial("_ShowUserInfo")
 }

Error message:
Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for                  
'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' 
has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast `ViewBag.Auth` to `boolean`

```
 @if ((bool)ViewBag.Auth)
 {
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ShowUserInfo");  } 
 }
```

Also you need to use `@{ }` syntax with `RenderPartial`

Answer (score 3):

Try using like this..

```
@if (ViewBag.Auth)
 {
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ShowUserInfo") }
 }
```